# Recursive CTE using function in recursive member

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, cross-apply

I need to created a list with all the subarticle (from all levels) of a given article. 
To retrieve only the children article of a parent article I use a function, GetArticleGroup(ArticleId, Index).

Executing the function would return something like this:

```
TRANS_ID    ARTICLE_GROUP_ID    ARTICLE_TRANS_ID    PIECES  SEQUENCE_NO DESCRIPTION IS_CHANGED  ART_INDEX
1   55  56  1   1       0   A
2   55  57  1   2       0   A
```

This is what I tried with no success:

```
WITH Subarticles AS (
    SELECT ARTICLE_TRANS_ID, ART_INDEX, cast(ARTICLE_TRANS_ID as varchar(max)) levels FROM dbo.GetArticleGroup(55, 'A') AG 
        UNION ALL
    SELECT S.ARTICLE_TRANS_ID, S.ART_INDEX, S.levels+','+cast(S.ARTICLE_TRANS_ID as varchar(max)) levels FROM Subarticles S
        CROSS APPLY 
    GetArticleGroup(S.ARTICLE_TRANS_ID, S.ART_INDEX) g where CHARINDEX(CAST(g.ARTICLE_TRANS_ID AS varchar(max)), s.levels)=0
)
SELECT top 30 ARTICLE_TRANS_ID, ART_INDEX, levels FROM Subarticles OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)
```

Expectation:

```
56, A
57, A
58, A
```

What I get instead, infinite loop:

```
56, A
57, A
57, A
...
57, A
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you need to create sequential values, a Tally is far better than a rCTE.

Comment: the sequential values are article IDs, so they are not necessary sequential.

Comment: The first select in the union returns the ARTICLE_TRANS_ID 56. You then call the function with that calue, returning one row from the outer apply.
But the row you add takes the value from the existing values, so the first recursion uses 56 as ARTICLE_TRANS_ID , and returns row nr 2 with ARTICLE_TRANS_ID  as 56.
Shouldn't it be g.ARTICLE_TRANS_ID you return in the second select?

Comment: YES! you were right! thank you!